# Are there any Java PDF libraries that integrate with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, pdf, spring-mvc

> More than that Spring is not tightly coupled with Servlets or JSP to
> render the View to the Clients. Integration with other View
> technologies like Velocity, Freemarker, Excel or Pdf is also possible
> now.

**~** [source](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-spring-3-mvc-introduction-spring-mvc-framework/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, look into:

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-pdf-file-via-abstractpdfview/

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/document/AbstractPdfView.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use Velocity to marry dynamic data into an XSL-FO and create the PDF using an XSL-FO engine, like the one from Apache.

You can use iText if you prefer doing it in Java classes.